# Edit Rich Text field inside Experience Manager directly

Tags: web8, dxa, experience-manager

Is it possible we insert Youtube video component into the Rich Text field directly, same as Image?

Is it possible to switch the Rich Text field to source code model directly without click the edit all fields button and open the component in another place?

Below is one screenshot to show what we want:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

SDL Web 8 (including 8.5) currently does not support adding anything other than images directly into a Rich Text field. Adding support for YouTube videos can however be done through using an ECL provider (https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/youtube_ecl_provider.aspx).

In the Experience Manager view, the source view of a Rich text field has deliberately been removed, to keep the interface simple. Once in the field, you can switch in the ribbon bar to Home, and choose the **Open in Form View** button, which will open the Component in the full featured view, which will allow you to edit the source of the Rich Text field among other things.